# nodejs access to module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does nodejs has some global module that i do not have to require?
I am just wondering why my code works for a time ago)))

```
module.exports = {
    get: function(req, res){
        //some code here
        _.map(req.query.data, function (val, key) {
            //come code here
        });
        //some code here
        async.parallel([......])


        re.send(.....)   
    }
}
```

I did not require underscore and async modules, and it's worked till today. Today it's threw error. Bassically i added "var async = require('async)" at the top of the file and it's start work again.
But i did not add _ = require('underscore') and still have access to all underscore methods.

Could anyone help me with this issue? I will be appreciate for any suggestion

Comment: Modules have own "global" scope, so they can't access other modules libraries. Can you provide full module code?

Comment: All modules SHOULD `require()` in the other modules that they depend on.  That's how you make modules reusable.  It's generally a bad practice to have modules that attach themselves to the global object.  Doing that might save a few `require()` statements in other modules, but then it makes things be dependent upon load order and it makes modules that won't work if used by themselves.  There's no way we can know which situation was happening to you without seeing your entire project.  But, you can just "fix" your code by requiring in all the things your module uses.

Answer (score 0):

In node.js there is a `global` object that has many things attached to it. Node tries to find the variables in the `global` object if it can't find it in any other local scope.

I'd look for something where you do `global._ = require('underscore')`.

Also, check your `underscore` version because I know the library used to **always** export the `_` variable to global scope whenever required.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i found what was that. in other module i had have

```
var module_name = require('module_name');
    module_name2 = require('module_name_2');
```

so module_name2 was on global scope.
thank you for ans